# Why does my Manifest.json shows "Page does not work offline"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

**My Problem:** I am trying to setup Progressive Web App for my site but my Manifest.json file's installability shows "Page does not work offline"

[image]

I tried to find what's causing this but couldn't. 
Can someone shed some light into this?

Comment: You are providing limited information, Can you show us your manifest code, your console, rest of the manifest view on devtools.

Comment: The Chrome Lighthouse tool may give you more info and some hints. You are attempting this on an HTTPS url?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your service worker might not have event listener for `fetch` event.
Which is basic requirement for PWA.

Just add:

```
 self.addEventListener('fetch',() => console.log("fetch"));
```

to your service worker or add `fetch` listener according to your requirement.

To get more info follow:
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-caching-files-with-service-worker#3_serve_files_from_the_cache

Answer (score 3):

Your site doesn't install a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). Without a service worker offline will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with service worker and the latest Chrome
add "offline_enabled": true to manifest.json to solve it